# Error in adding image inside a label defined inside a function Tkinter python gui

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, graphical-programming

This is the code and expected output for a revive box that i created for a practice project
`revboxppl` frame contains three labels `l1`,`l2`,`l3` and each label contains the same image
`ill.png`

[image: ill.png]  <--image

```
#FRAME FOR BORDER
revbox = Frame(root, bg="#C5B358", bd=10, relief="ridge")
revbox.place(relwidth=0.19, relheight=0.1, relx=0.74, rely=0.76)     

#FRAME OF PURPLE COLOUR
revboxppl = Frame(revbox, bg="#5B0A91")
revboxppl.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#LABELS ON "reboxppl" FRAME
pathg="ill.png"
kl = Image.open(pathg)
kl = kl.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
rimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(kl)
l1 = Label(revboxppl, image=rimg, bg="#5B0A91")
l1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
l2 = Label(revboxppl, image=rimg, bg="#5B0A91")
l2.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.3, relx=0.345)
l3 = Label(revboxppl, image=rimg, bg="#5B0A91")
l3.place(relheight=1, relwidth=0.3, relx=0.696)
```

[image: Revive label outside function]  <--image

[image: expected output]  <--image

but when i used this segment inside my actual program the labels worked but the image `ill.png` was not added

[image: Revive label defined inside function]

[image: actual output]

Is it not possible to add an image inside function or am i just too dumb
please help..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Yo it helped now its working thank you jizhihaosama